# Simple brute forcer not working

Tags: python, brute-force, network-security

I am trying to write a very simple brute forcer to try to crack a password protected zip file. The password for the file is "red".

```
import zipfile;
zfile = zipfile.ZipFile('password_archive.zip')

words = open('/usr/share/dict/words')
for word in words.readlines():
    try:
        password = word.strip('/n')
        zfile.extractall(pwd=password)
        print "Password found: "+ password
        exit(0)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

Console:

```
('Bad password for file', <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x1004ca500>)
('Bad password for file', <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x1004ca500>)
('Bad password for file', <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x1004ca500>)
('Bad password for file', <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x1004ca500>)
('Bad password for file', <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x1004ca500>)
('Bad password for file', <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x1004ca500>)
('Bad password for file', <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x1004ca500>)
('Bad password for file', <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x1004ca500>)
Password found: Abasgi
```

Not really sure what is going on here. Abasgi isn't the correct password, but the script seems to fail on an incorrect password, and seems to find the correct one. I think I have set the password variable in the correct place in the loop.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=password+hash+collision

Comment: Its not hash collision I'm not comparing a word dict against a hash. You don't know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change:

```
password = word.strip('/n')
```

To:

```
password = word.strip("\n")
```

But you might as well just:

```
password = word.strip()
```

See the strip [documenation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip):

> Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters
>   removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters are
>   removed. If given and not None, chars must be a string; the characters
>   in the string will be stripped from the both ends of the string this
>   method is called on.

And make sure that `red` is in your words list `Red` was in mine so I had to add:

```
zfile.extractall(pwd=password.lower())
```

After those changes it all seems to work great:

```
import zipfile
zfile = zipfile.ZipFile("file.zip")

words = open("/usr/share/dict/words")
for word in words.readlines():
     try:
        password = word.strip("\n")
        zfile.extractall(pwd=password.lower())
        print "Password found: "+ password
        exit(0)
     except Exception, e:
        pass
```